# Banco de Dados SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, select

Olá! Estou em treinamento em Suporte e estou tendo dificuldade em entender a lógica do select, preciso fazer script por exemplo: trazer os status da tabela Critérios.

Comment: Acho que podemos explicar o funcionamento do select, mas indicar curso é totalmente fora de escopo do nosso site.

Comment: Como acesso a explicação? Não seria indicação de escolas, mas do nome do curso, exemplo: Modelagem de dados ou Projetando e implementando dados, etc. Tem como me orientar?

Comment: Edite sua pergunta clicando em [edit] e remove o que for off e foca na pegunta do Select mesmo, logo que alguém responde ;-)

Comment: Quanto a cursos de curta duração, não é propósito deste site recomendar ou indicar cursos. A ideia aqui é solucionar problemas referentes a programação.

Answer (score 4):

O seu SQL seria isso:

```sql
SELECT status FROM Critérios
```

A lógica é a seguinte:

- Uma consulta `SELECT` sempre produz uma tabela de resultados.
- Pesquisa-se todos os registros da tabela `Critérios`. Nenhum filtro é aplicado, e portanto todos os registros são retornados (se quisesse filtrar, uma claúsula `WHERE` seria necessária). Cada registro encontrado corresponderá a uma linha da tabela.
- Seleciona-se a coluna `status` dos registros obtidos. Você poderia selecionar mais colunas, mas como está selecionando apenas essa, sua tabela conterá apenas a coluna `status` e nada mais.
- Como resultado, você terá uma lista de todos os status existentes na tabela `Critérios`. Poderão haver repetições no caso de vários registros diferentes da tabela `Critérios` terem o mesmo `status`.